# JSON.dictionaryObject is null in Alamofire swift 3

Tags: json, swift, alamofire, swifty-json

I have a JSON in following format:

```
postJson ={"firstname":"Vishal","lastname":"raskar","username":"vishal123","password":"123456","confirmpassword":"123456","email":"raskarvishal7@gmail.com","timezone":"1","accountid":"12345","phoneno":"8655012753"}
```

(Data type of postJson is JSON i.e swiftyJSON)

Now I want to hit on server through Alamofire, so I need to Post JSON data in dictionary format in `parameters : ___`, e.g.:

```
Alamofire.request(URL, method: .post, parameters: postJson.dictionaryObject, encoding: JSONEncoding.default,headers: "Content-Type": "application/json").responseJSON { response in switch response.result {

case .success(let data):

case .failure(let error):

}
```

so basically I tried to convert my JSON in dictionary by `postJson.dictionaryObject`. But always gets null from `postJson.dictionaryObject` (even though data is present in `postJson`).

I tried all combinations like `postJson.dictionaryValue`, `postJson.dictionary`, but no success.

I then tried to convert `postJson` to `Data`, and then dictionary:

```
if let data = postJson.data(using: .utf8) {

 do {

return try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String: AnyObject]
            } 
catch {

 print(error.localizedDescription)

 }

 }
```

and then post through Alamofire, now getting response. What am I doing wrong? I want to use my first option.

Comment: You can directly use `["firstname":"Vishal","lastname":"raskar","username":"vishal123","password":"123456","confirmpassword":"123456","email":"raskarvishal7@gmail.com","timezone":"1","accountid":"12345","phoneno":"8655012753"]` as parameters of the request no need to convert it to swiftyjson object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using Swift 3 / Alamofire 4.0

This is how you would define the "parameters" parameter according to Alamofire documentation:

```
let parameters: Parameters = ["foo": "bar"]

Alamofire.request(urlString, method: .get, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default)
    .downloadProgress(queue: DispatchQueue.global(qos: .utility)) { progress in
        print("Progress: \(progress.fractionCompleted)")
    }
    .validate { request, response, data in
        // Custom evaluation closure now includes data (allows you to parse data to dig out error messages if necessary)
        return .success
    }
    .responseJSON { response in
        debugPrint(response)
    }
```

To learn more, [click here](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire)